# Adjusting the image to the background according to color design

Tags: html, css

I have design in `Adobe XD` like this, which is the same on each subpage:

[image]

Is there a way to get this result?

Here is basic code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #4D4D4D;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/xSc3fpc/image.png" alt="image">
```

Is not substantial centering image for me right now. I don't know how to write CSS/HTML to fit the design. Body color is `#4D4D4D`

Thank you for any help

Comment: Add a [`width:100%`](https://jsfiddle.net/74ko69dj/) on the image? I don't understand the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the img element, add the image in the background and use the background-blend-mode

```css
body {
    background: #4D4D4D url(https://i.ibb.co/xSc3fpc/image.png);
    position: relative;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50%;
    height: 400px;
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, `background-blend-mode` is something new for me. Thanks!